# Virtuemart/Joomla Categories with over 1000 items very flaky

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

works 90% with firefox 2% with IE or Chrome. Get error that it can save the query result - any ideas? Running on a godaddy hosted site so limited control of mysql

Comment: Left out this is specifically when browsing by categories - searching for keywords is ok - but using categories it times out

Answer (score 0):

what are the errors specifically?

try running some tests with script-debugging enabled in IE8 Developer Tools and see if there any noteable errors or warnings indicated.